# SQL Case statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a sql query and it works, but I get only half results:

```
  (q1.VariableName LIKE
        CASE WHEN @Variablename IS NULL THEN ('e%')
        ELSE @Variablename
        END)
```

The thing I want is : 
If the @Variablename is NOT NULL then q1.VariableName = @Variablename.

```
If it is NULL,
 then q1.VariableName like 'e%' 
 or q1.VariableName like 'b%' and q1.VARIABLENAME not LIKE '%MAIL%'
```

But, I am unable to get it. Can anyone tell me, where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this is the `where` clause, you would be better off avoiding using `CASE` altogether:

```
   ((@Variablename IS NULL
     and (q1.VariableName LIKE 'e%'
          or q1.VariableName like 'b%' 
          and q1.VARIABLENAME not LIKE '%MAIL%'))
or q1.VariableName = @Variablename)
```

Since `null` is never equal to anything, `q1.VariableName = @Variablename)` will always evaluate to false when `@Variablename` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the isnull() function to check for NULL. If @VariableName is NULL the function will replace it with 'e%'.

```
WHERE q1.VariableName LIKE isnull(@VariableName, 'e%')
```

If it's NOT NULL it would have to be equal to q1.VariableName, provided @VariableName doesn't contain a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

OR can be used in the where clause

```
where (  q1.VariableName = @Variablename)
      OR ( @VariableName IS  NULL And (q1.VariableName like 'e%' 
 or q1.VariableName like 'b%' and q1.VARIABLENAME not LIKE '%MAIL%'))
```